# Htaccess permanent redirect query urls to one location

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url, redirect

I can't figure out how to redirect all query urls to another location.

Example:
I want to redirect all urls that follow this pattern:

https://www.test.com/index.php?option=com_sobipro&pid=**[any numbers]**&sid=**[any numbers]**&itemid=646

To new location: https://www.test.com/some/place/

I've googled for hours trying to learn and this is what I've come up with so far but I'm not sure this is right.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} option=com_sobipro&pid=(.*)&sid=(.*)&itemid=646$
RewriteRule ^$ /some/place/ [R=301,L]
```

How to check a requested (and dead) url for pattern and send it to another adress if conditions are met using htaccess? Any guidence would be grately appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Place this rule as your top most rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} option=com_sobipro&pid=[^&]+&sid=[^&]+&itemid=646
RewriteRule ^ /some/place/? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: No, I'm sorry but it doesn't seem to work. So frustrating!